# In Nextjs reaclidatePath followed by form submission requires hard reload for page navigation

Tags: next.js, web-applications, fetch, next.js13, app-router

In my Next.js 14 application, I'm encountering an issue with `revalidatPath` listing page upon adding a record from the create page. after form submission, I've attempted to revalidate the data by putting `revalidatePath`. However, it fails to work properly, leading to infinite loading during page navigation by clicking any `<Link>` or using `router.push`. Oddly enough, after a hard reload following the form submission, the revalidation starts functioning as intended.